# I am playing audio on one channel but can still hear it on the other channel

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, core-audio

I am using core audio to play a tone on one channel. When I am testing it on an iPhone using a headphone, you can hear the tone, very low, also on the wrong side. So lets say I am playing on mBuffers[0] (LEFT) you will still hear a very low tone on mBuffers[1] (RIGHT) when I am placing 0.0 in this channel.

Here is how my code looks like:

```
// configuring the unit
AudioStreamBasicDescription streamFormat;
streamFormat.mSampleRate = SAMPLE_RATE;
streamFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;

kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
streamFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagsNativeFloatPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved;
streamFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
streamFormat.mBytesPerPacket = FOUR_BYTES_PER_FLOAT;
streamFormat.mBytesPerFrame = FOUR_BYTES_PER_FLOAT;
streamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
streamFormat.mBitsPerChannel = FOUR_BYTES_PER_FLOAT * EIGHT_BITS_PER_BYTE;
err = AudioUnitSetProperty (_outputUnit,
                            kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                            kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                            0,
                            &streamFormat,
                            sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription));
```

// and this is the render callback
    ToneGen *toneGen = (__bridge ToneGen*)inRefCon;

```
// first clean the buffers
for (int iBuffer=0; iBuffer < ioData->mNumberBuffers; ++iBuffer) {
    memset(ioData->mBuffers[iBuffer].mData, 0, ioData->mBuffers[iBuffer].mDataByteSize);
}



for (int frame = 0; frame < inNumberFrames; frame++) {

    Float32 *dataLeft = (Float32*)ioData->mBuffers[0].mData;
    Float32 *dataRight = (Float32*)ioData->mBuffers[1].mData;

    Float32 leftFrame = (Float32)[toneGen renderNextFrameLeft:YES];
    Float32 rightFrame = 0.0;


    dataLeft[frame] = leftFrame;

    dataRight[frame] = rightFrame;
}

return noErr;
```

What is the reason it is played on both channels? Any direction will help

Comment: It sounds to me like you might have some crosstalk from channel 1 into channel 2. In other words some of the signal is leaking from one channel into the other. I'd look at the headphones first. Do they share a common cable to one cup or are there 2 cables? Does the crosstalk happen if you swap channels? You could also eliminate your code as the culprit by playing a one channel signal from a different player.

Comment: Also check that the left and right channels in the source material are really complete separated.

Comment: @marko I was assuming that was the case by virtue of the `rightFrame = 0.0.` in the posted code.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will check the code again and look into the memory of the buffers to be sure.

Comment: After checking it in a professional sound studio, it seams that all Apple products (laptops and iPhones) are not playing clear stereo sound. You cannot play only left or right side. You will always have some sound on the other side. It is probably a stereo widening effect that Apple is running on the output.